# Filter List using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have one class:

```
public class Shop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And one List instance:

```
var Shops = new List<Shop>()
{
    new Shop()
    {
        Name = "Shop 1",
        DateTime = DateTime.Now
    },
    new Shop()
    {
        Name = "Shop 2",
        DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
    }
};
```

I want to filter the `Shops` list and take only the `Shop` with the largest (i.e. latest) date.

How can I do this with LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var shop = S.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

And the result is below:

[image]

Comment: this is using Lambda, OP wanted LINQ: see my answer

Comment: LINQ is based on lambdas. Also `FirstOrDefault` and `OrderByDescending` are both part of extensions that form LINQ. Note further that LINQ supports two types of syntax: method syntax, as in my example; and query syntax as in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be OrderByDescending and then take the first one

```
Shop k = S.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: this is using Lambda, OP wanted LINQ: see my answer

Comment: I think both are LINQ. This one is just using Lambdas! Check this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391370/is-it-linq-or-lambda

Answer (score 0):

```
var sel = (from shop in Shops orderby shop.DateTime descending select shop).Take(1);
```