# updating a list using linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have list in which I want to update is active flag from all user like

```
userList:[
    {'name':'a', isActive:'Y'},
    {'name':'b', isActive:'N'},
    {'name':'c', isActive:'Y'},
    {'name':'d', isActive:'N'},
];
```

I want to change isActive from Y to N and from N to Y, my updated list will look like below

```
userList:[
    {'name':'a', isActive:'N'},
    {'name':'b', isActive:'Y'},
    {'name':'c', isActive:'N'},
    {'name':'d', isActive:'Y'},
];
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not use plain old `foreach`?

Comment: `foreach (var user in userList) user.isActive = userIsActive == 'Y' ? 'N' : 'Y';` ?

Comment: I did this with loops now I want to achieve the same with linq

Comment: @TWMTV but.. why? also: if `isActive` never will have any other values than `Y` and `N` - how about using a boolean instead?

Comment: we store is active as (Y/N)

Comment: I am learning linq but I can't find any example for this, help will be appreciated

Comment: *I want to achieve the same with linq* - you can't because *it's not what LINQ is for*

Comment: (I say "can't" - what I really mean is "shouldn't" - clarified in an answer)

Comment: Yeah it looks like the main confusion here is that you want to achieve this using lambda rather than LINQ (a good read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391370/is-it-linq-or-lambda), if you could clarify that, this could help with an appropriate answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ stands for Language Integrated *Query* - it's a tool for query, not modifying data. LINQ queries are not supposed to have side effects, like "every time you run it it changes the data and gives a different answer". It's also a side effect to change other data not related to the data being queried..

If you want to permanently change the items in your list using a lamdba based approach, you can use `ForEach` on List - this is not a LINQ thing; it's a List thing:

```
myList.ForEach(item => item.isActive = (item.isActive == 'Y' ? 'N' : 'Y'));
```

..but this isn't significantly different to the code Matt Watson posted in the comment, using a normal `foreach`

---

If you want to calculate-every-time-from-the-data the inverse of the current active, that's fine to do with LINQ:

```
myList.Select(item => 
  new Item{ 
    name = item.name, 
    isActive = (item.isActive == 'Y' ? 'N' : 'Y')
  }
);
```

You can run this over and over and the output is stable; if the myList data hasn't changed then the output from this will be a list that has items that are flipped in their active status

---

Here's a LINQ query that has a side effect; it modifies the array every time it runs:

[image]

The first time, Select did `a[idx]++` which e.g. bumped array index 0 up from 1 to 2, but the `++` operation returns the value before the increment e.g. 1 (and the `a[0]` is now 2).. This means you see "the original array" i.e. `1, 2, 3, 4` reflected in the `z1` result, but `z2` is the bumped up once (and the `a` is full of numbers that have been bumped twice)

Don't do this; it will cause a lot of problems. (I deliberately didn't put the code in as text, to hinder copy-pasting of code we shouldn't write)